# Change child target of Firebase .on in a react component and stop listening for changes to previous child

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am attempting to use Firebase for a chat app.

I am trying to have a listener on the currently selected message to check if new messages have arrived.

On my "MessageBody" component I have set up a realtime listener using .on("value"). Code below:

```
MessageBody.js

class MessageBody extends Component {

    getMessages = (turnOffRef) => {
        const db = firebase.database();
        const newMessageRef = db.ref().child('messages').child(this.props.currentChatId);
        newMessageRef.on('value', snap => {
        console.log("CHAT ID IN SNAP: ", this.props.currentChatId);
        this.props.onGotMessageContent(snap.val());
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getMessages();
    }

//... other unrelated code

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onGotMessageContent: (messages) => dispatch(actions.setMessageContent(messages)),
    };
};
```

redux message action.js

```
export const setMessageContent = (messages) => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.ADD_SELECTED_CHAT_TO_STATE,
        messages: messages,
    };
};
```

Redux messages reducer:

```
const addSelectedChatToState = (state, action) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        currentMessage: action.messages,
    };
};

// other code...

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        // other cases:... 
        case actionTypes.ADD_SELECTED_CHAT_TO_STATE: return newMessageReceived(state, action);
        default: return state;
    }
};
```

[image]

This does receive realtime updates for the currently selected "messages" child. However, if I have previously been listening to another message (sent to MessageBody via props), I get a snap event any time either message receives an update.

So, in the above instance I was previously listening to "-L3ylXhU3zSNvPB3h_uS", then sent a new reference of "-L3ylh4b4yuSRvYkH1ai" via props. But now any time there is an update on either Child of message I receive an update when I only wish to for the current this.props.CurrentChatId.

If I first go to chat "-L3ylXhU3zSNvPB3h_uS", I get the following in console:

```
CHAT ID IN SNAP:  -L3ylXhU3zSNvPB3h_uS
```

If I then go to chat "-L3ymmWaLe9qCmAeJlO7", I get the following in console:

```
CHAT ID IN SNAP:  -L3ymmWaLe9qCmAeJlO7
```

However, if a message is then sent to me on message L3ylXhU3zSNvPB3h_uS, while I am still in L3ymmWaLe9qCmAeJlO7, I get the following in console:

```
CHAT ID IN SNAP:  -L3ylXhU3zSNvPB3h_uS
```

Is there a way to kill off the old listener upon changing the child, but keep the current listener active for new messages in this child?

Comment: you use `off` method on a reference to stop listening , for example `messageRef.off()`

Comment: Thanks Ali, won't that turn off the current listener also? I am looking to kill the current listener and replace with the new id. I will have a play in componentWillReceiveProps and see if I can work something out.

Comment: can you post the code of `onGetMessageContent`

Comment: Sure, I edited to hopefully better explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this could help you

I declared the message reference as property of the class(Component) , then in `getMessages` I stop listening if there listener is already set and then listen again to new chatId , I add `componentWillReceiveProps` so when the props changed the `getMessages` called again with new props , also when the component will unmount the listener should be stoped.

checkout the code

```
class MessageBody extends Component 
{
    consrtuctor(props){
        super(props);
        this.messageRef = null;
    }

    getMessages = (chatId) => {

        if(this.messageRef)
            this.messageRef.off();

        const db = firebase.database();
        this.messageRef = db.ref().child('messages').child(this.props.currentChatId);
        this.messageRef.on('value', snap => {
            console.log("CHAT ID IN SNAP: ", this.props.currentChatId);
            this.props.onGotMessageContent(snap.val());
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        let chatId = this.props.currentChatId;
        this.getMessages(chatId);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        let chatId = nextProps.currentChatId;
        this.getMessages(chatId);   
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        if(this.messageRef)
            this.messageRef.off();
    }

    //.....other code

};
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for taking the time to help Ali. Really appreciated.

Comment: happy to help you :)